# Self-signed SSL Certificate for Nginx not working with Chrome

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I've generated a Self-signed SSL Certificate and Authority for my localhost nginx dev environment and imported the Certificate Authority in both Firefox and Chrome.

**- Firefox: works perfectly, the certificate is recognized/valid and HTTPS works**

**- Chrome: Getting an error and the site won't load**

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

[image: This site can’t provide a secure connection]

**Here's what I did, step by step**

Step 1. Created a file `/tmp/openssl.cnf` with

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = New York
L = Rochester
O = Localhost CA
OU = Development
CN = localhost

[ CA_default ]
copy_extensions = copy

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alternate_names
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign, keyEncipherment

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
# Support subdomains
#DNS.2 = *.domain.local
```

Step 2. Generated a certificate/key pair with

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/localhost.key -out /etc/ssl/localhost.crt -config /tmp/openssl.cnf
```

Step 3. Generated the custom certificate authority

```
cat /etc/ssl/localhost.key /etc/ssl/localhost.crt > /etc/ssl/custom-ca.crt
```

Step 4. Imported /etc/ssl/custom-ca.crt as a trusted Certificate Authority for the OS (Ubuntu) by doing:

```
mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
cp /etc/ssl/custom-ca.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/
echo "extra/foo.crt" >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
update-ca-certificates
```

Step 5. Imported /etc/ssl/custom-ca.crt as a trusted Certificate Authority in both browsers and restarted them

**And here's my nginx configuration**

```
upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 http2 ipv6only=on default_server;

        server_name _;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/web-access.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost.key;

        root /var/www/mysite/public;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @backend; # Try static files first, then NodeJs
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  256;
        gzip_proxied     any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types  text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml font/truetype font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_disable     "msie6";

        ## All static files will be served directly.
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|webp|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 365d;
            add_header Cache-Control public;

            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;

            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }

        location @backend {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the certificate to the certificate store for the OS itself?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, just tried that as well. Same error, SSL is valid and recognized in FF but not in Chrome. I will add this step to my question, Thanks for the suggestion!